# How to use hash in perl to reduce the use of loops?

Tags: perl, loops, hash

For example, first, I have identified several key words. Then, in another file, I want to find lines that matches these key words exactly.

Using loop, I would loop through the file for each key word. So if there are 10 key words, I would loop the file 10 times. But if the file is huge, this method would be very time inefficient.

I heard proper use of hash could ease such a situation but never saw an example. So exactly how to use hash to achieve the same goal while using loop only once? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a solution whose time taken is proportional to the size of the file and to the number of keywords (O(N*K)). You would like a solution where the time taken is not affected by the number of keywords (O(N)).

You could indeed achieve this using a hash.

```
my @keywords = ...;

my %keywords = map { $_ => 1 } @keywords;
while (<$fh>) {
    my @words = split ' ';                # To be improved.
    if (grep { $keywords{$_} } @words) {  # Replace with foreach loop to exit ASAP.
       ...
    }
}
```

I'd use a regex match.

```
my @keywords = ...;

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @keywords;
my $re = qr/$pat/;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/(?:^|\s)$re(?:\s|\z)/) {  # To be improved.
       ...
    }
}
```